# 0 in FFT spectrum are white?, why? - OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[image]

The image represent what I'm doing in a openCV exercise whit Fourier Transform. This is an exercise to eliminate periodic noise. I'm detecting the bands which make the noise and with a mask I delete this. As you can see I'm doing the product from the `dft_shift` with the mask. I'm assuming that the product of that are 0, my question is: Why are that lines white if that values are 0 ???

Code:

```
dft = cv2.dft(img_float32, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)    #calcula la transf. Fourier 
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft) #proyecta los cuadrantes de la imagen 
dft_shift = dft_shift*mask2
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])
```

Complete script [Here](https://github.com/gcmurillo/DIP/blob/master/transformadas/code_Fourier/ej_1/ej_1Fourier.py)

Comment: That is absolutely not the OP's problem. He has `inf` values in his `product` image array. In any case, the standard `'gray'` colormap in Matplotlib will always by default show the smallest values as black and the largest values as white. The choice is not arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

If you print out the values in your `product` image array, you'll find that all of the pixels in the white bands actually have a value of `-inf`, not `0`. In your code, as part of the process of creating `product` you use `np.log` to rescale some of your data. That data has `0`'s in it, and the result of `np.log(0)` is `-inf`.

You can fix this in a couple of different ways. The simplest option will be to just replace all `-inf` values in `product` with `0`. After you create `product`, if you add the following line:

```
product[np.isneginf(product)] = 0
```

then when you plot `product` it will have black bands, like you expected:

[image]

## Deep dive

Here's why you're ending up with `-inf` in `product`. This is the line in your code that creates `product`:

```
product = 20*np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]))
```

If we split this into two lines, we can figure out what's going on:

```
magnitude = cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1])
product = 20*np.log(magnitude)
```

`magnitude` has `0`'s along the bands like you expected. However, if you try to plot magnitude directly, you end up with a very dark plot that doesn't show much:

[image]

The reason for this is that Matplotlib will scale your data when picking colors so that the smallest values in the image array are black, and the largest values are white. The issue here is that the largest value in `magnitude` is much much larger than almost every other value. Thus, you get a few pixels of white (near the center), and every other pixel is colored nearly black.

You can make the plot of `magnitude` show a little more of the underlying detail by passing `vmax=1000` to the `imshow` function you use to plot your images. This sets an explicit maximum data value for the colormap:

[image]

This is far from ideal, since it means that a large part of your image is shown as fully saturated white, regardless of its underlying details.

In reality, you already have a better fix for this issue in your code: you rescale the data in `magnitude` using `np.log`. The result of this rescaling, the `product` array, will have all of its values much closer together. This has the beneficial effect of allowing you to see the fine details in the image when you plot `product`. However, the problem you run into here is that the log of 0 is infinity:

```
print(np.log(0))
# this outputs
# -inf
```

Thus, the bands of `0` in `magnitude` become bands of `-inf` in `product`. Matplotlib deals with these `-inf` values by coloring them the same as it would the maximum value in your input array (ie as white). Thus, you get the bands of white that you're seeing in your plotted `product` image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.